# php. neatbeans. adding whihte space before and after functions argument

Tags: php, netbeans

I want configure netbeans for PHP. how to make that it automatically put white spaces before and after function argument:

```
myfunction($arg1) {...
```

But whant:

```
myfunction( $arg1 ) {...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly to have spaces around args... Anyway you can customize formatting options in:

> Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting

Here you have to select *PHP Language* and you can customize all coding styles (there's more than only *Tabs and Indents*).